# Finite sum of right ideals is finite sum of left ideals

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring with $1$ and let $R=I_1\oplus I_2 \cdots \oplus I_n$ where $I_i$ are right ideals of $R$.

I need to show that:

i) $I_i=x_iR$ for some $x_i\in I_i$

ii) $x_i^2=x_i$ and $x_ix_j=0$ if $i\neq j$

iii) $R=Re_1\oplus \cdots \oplus Re_n$

I really have no idea where to start with this ( I know people tend to get slightly annoyed by this sorry) so any ideas of where to start would be great.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem gets a lot easier once you see the following ideas. They should stick with you in future problems about decompositions of rings.

Hints:

Your candidates for $x_i$'s are $1=\sum x_i$, where $x_i\in I_i$.

i) Use the equation above, and multiply on the right by any $y_i\in I_i$, keeping in mind that the sum is direct.

ii) Use the equation above, and multiply on the right with a fixed $x_j$, keeping in mind that the sum is *direct*, and you'll be able to deduce all of these.

iii) $Re_1+ \cdots + Re_n$ is clearly a left ideal containing $1$. Notice that the result in ii) is left-right symmetric, and use it to show the sum is direct.

Comment: Thanks. For the last part can I just apply the who process again but this time on the right and I get the same thing? where the representation of $1$ as a direct sum is unique?

Comment: @hmmmm Yes: since $2$ is left-right symmetric, you'll be able to do both versions.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: write $1$ in coordinate form.